# can't remove child from jQuery gallery on close

Tags: jquery

Noob at this.  Started using jQuery last week and after about 10 hours of reading this site and the api have to ask this and hope for a direction.

Trying to remove the last image clicked from a gallery, so next gallery clicked will load first image instead of last image. (www.cooloradan.com).

My janky code (taken mostly from someone else):

```
function loadPhoto($url, $caption) {/*Image pre-loader*/
    showPreloader();
    var img = new Image();
    $(img).load( function() {
        $(img).hide();
        hidePreloader();

     }).attr({ "src": $url });

    $('#largephotoc1').css('background-image','url("' + $url + '")');
    $('#largephotoc1').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephotoc2').css('background-image','url("' + $url + '")');
    $('#largephotoc2').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephotoc3').css('background-image','url("' + $url + '")');
    $('#largephotoc3').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephotoc4').css('background-image','url("' + $url + '")');
    $('#largephotoc4').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephoto3d1').css('background-image','url("' + $url + '")');
    $('#largephoto3d1').data('caption', $caption);
}

/* When a thumbnail is clicked*/
 $('.thumb_container').click(function() {
      var handler = $(this).find('.large_image');
      var newsrc  = handler.attr('src');
      var newcaption  = handler.attr('rel');
      loadPhoto(newsrc, newcaption);
 });

 $('.close-reveal-modal').click(function() {
    $('.thumb_container').find('.large_image').remove();
 });
```

html:

```
<div id="myModalc3" class="reveal-modal">
    <div class="mainframe">
        <div id="largephotoc3">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnailimage">
        <div class="thumb_container">
            <div class="large_thumb">
                <img src="images/album/modalthumbs/3d1.6.jpg" class="large_thumb_image" alt="thumb" />
                <img alt="" src="images/album/modallarge/3d1.6.jpg" class="large_image" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal"><img src="images/icons/close.png"  /></a>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't know exactly what I'm trying to ask, but I'll keep looking and trying different things all night I'm sure though.

Comment: this is driving me nuts.  would really appreciate some response, I would increase your points even if wrong.  just need some different idea or direction as to where I'm wrong. these lines                    $('.close-reveal-modal').click(function()
  {
  $('.thumb_container').find('.large_image').remove();

  });                                                         Just remove the gallery on next click.  Closest thing I can find to something that actually does something though.  Keep on keepin on.  I know this would be fairly simple if I had a better idea what I was looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little confused about parts of your question, but I think what you want is to change this...

```
 $('.close-reveal-modal').click(function() {
    $('.thumb_container').find('.large_image').remove();
 });
```

to this...

```
 $('.close-reveal-modal').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().find('.large_image').remove();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, gave me a new direction.  Didn't quite solve, but I needed to clean up my messy code first.  In a couple days if I know how to ask I will.  Right now I don't.  Still learning and in over my head, just not clicking.