# Need help removing image in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

12 hours later still trying to figure out how to remove a clicked gallery image on close.  Live example [here](http://www.cooloradan.com/).  Trouble is when a thumbnail is clicked inside a gallery, that thumbs 'src' image carries over to next gallery.  Tried hundreds of ways to remove, but don't think I'm anywhere close, noobie.  Last few lines of javascript which can be seen here
http://jsfiddle.net/coryd3033/5LPqZ/
just remove the image holder all together in the next gallery, instead of the last image in the previous gallery.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you. The functionality I'm looking for is to simply remove an image from the holder on close.  Not so simple though:(

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't remove child from jQuery gallery on close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449903/cant-remove-child-from-jquery-gallery-on-close)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
$('.close').click(function() {
    $('.imageHolder').fadeOut(500, function(){
         $('.imageHolder img').remove();
    });
});
```

This means: When close button is clicked, fade out the image holder within half a second. When that completes, remove any images from the image holder.

Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really messy.  Best I can tell, your problem is not with the `<img/>` src, but rather `#largephotoc1`'s `background-image` property. After your modal is opened, you need to call your `loadPhoto()` function to set `#largephotoc1`'s background image to the first image in the set.

Comment: The background image to all `#largephotoXX`'s is being set in loadPhoto()

Comment: You got me thinking closer.  Post my answer here in a few when my 8 hours are up.  Not sure if it's the right way but it works.  Thanks

Comment: Glad I could point you in the right direction. If it works, it works! That's right in my book. You can always clean/tighten it up.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Chimoo and Set Sail (I cleaned up my code atleast as far as indentation after your and am not I am's comments).  This gave me the functionality I needed and everything works perfectly.  Don't know how, logically doesn't make sense.
But is there any way I can simplify this block.  Its basically three functions performing similar tasks.  But it works :) 
Thanks guys.

```
function loadDefault($lD, $caption){
showPreloader();
var img = new Image();  
$(img).load( function()
{
    $(img).hide();
    hidePreloader();

}).attr({ "src": $lD });

    $('#largephoto').css('background-image','url("' + $lD + '")');
    $('#largephoto').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephotoc1').css('background-image','url("images/album/modallarge/c1.1.jpg")');
    $('#largephotoc1').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephotoc2').css('background-image','url("images/album/modallarge/c3.1.jpg")');
    $('#largephotoc2').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephotoc3').css('background-image','url("images/album/modallarge/c4.1.jpg")');
    $('#largephotoc3').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephoto3d1').css('background-image','url("images/album/modallarge/3d1.1.jpg")');
    $('#largephoto3d1').data('caption', $caption);

}

$('.reveal-modal').ready(function(){
    //var source = $('.st_thumbs').click
    var handler = $(this).find('.large_image');
    var newsrc = handler.attr('src');
    var newcaption = handler.attr('rel');
    loadDefault(newsrc, newcaption);

});

function loadPhoto($url, $caption){
showPreloader();
var img = new Image();  
$(img).load( function()
{
    $(img).hide();
    hidePreloader();

}).attr({ "src": $url });

    $('#largephotoc1').css('background-image','url("' + $url + '")');
    $('#largephotoc1').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephotoc2').css('background-image','url("' + $url + '")');
    $('#largephotoc2').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephotoc3').css('background-image','url("' + $url + '")');
    $('#largephotoc3').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephotoc4').css('background-image','url("' + $url + '")');
    $('#largephotoc4').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephoto3d1').css('background-image','url("' + $url + '")');
    $('#largephoto3d1').data('caption', $caption);

}

$('.thumb_container').click(function()
{
    //var source = $('.st_thumbs').click
    var handler = $(this).find('.large_image');
    var newsrc = handler.attr('src');
    var newcaption = handler.attr('rel');
    loadPhoto(newsrc, newcaption);

});

function removePhoto($lD, $caption){
showPreloader();
var img = new Image();  
$(img).load( function()
{
    $(img).hide();
    hidePreloader();

}).attr({ "src": $lD });

    $('#largephotoc1').css('background-image','url("images/album/modallarge/c1.1.jpg")');
    $('#largephotoc1').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephotoc2').css('background-image','url("images/album/modallarge/c3.1.jpg")');
    $('#largephotoc2').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephotoc3').css('background-image','url("images/album/modallarge/c4.1.jpg")');
    $('#largephotoc3').data('caption', $caption);
    $('#largephoto3d1').css('background-image','url("images/album/modallarge/3d1.1.jpg")');
    $('#largephoto3d1').data('caption', $caption);

}

$('.close-reveal-modal').click(function()
{
    //var source = $('.st_thumbs').click
    var handler = $(this).find('.large_image');
    var newsrc = handler.attr('src');
    var newcaption = handler.attr('rel');
    removePhoto(newsrc, newcaption);

});
```